# Why Wordpress host does not work in Bigdump?

Tags: database, wordpress, mysqli

I´m trying to import a big sql file for a Wordpress project that we should be really simple.
I would like to use [BigDump](https://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/) because PhpMyAdmin make a 413 error.

BigDump does not connect with the server.

I got this error :

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H�te inconnu.
> Database connection failed due to php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H�te inconnu

I report data from `wp-config.php` into `bigdump.php` like this :

- $db_server   <=> DB_HOST
- $db_name     <=> DB_NAME
- $db_username <=> DB_USER
- $db_password <=> DB_PASSWORD

Notice : DB_HOST is neither localhost nor 127.0.0.1

This is the php code which run this part :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_server, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
  
if (mysqli_connect_error()) 
{ echo ("<p class=\"error\">Database connection failed due to ".mysqli_connect_error()."</p>\n");
    echo ("<p>Edit the database settings in BigDump configuration, or contact your database provider.</p>\n");
    $error=true;
}
```

It´s so weird,..should I input other thing in $db_server ?

Someone one could help me ?

Comment: "Hôte inconnu" looks like an unreachable host. Have you tried researching the error and considering that you're trying to a database server that isn't accessible from where you run this code?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, the problem is the host. I´m trying to connect from local php file (using Xampp) into database on the cloud. It´s not possible ?

Comment: Usually a database server is not accessible from the internet, only from select web servers ran by the hoster.